# How to correctly reference other JSON Schema Documents ($ref)

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-ref

I've read through the RFCs regarding JSON Schema and JSON pointers, but I'm still struggling to understand how to correctly reference other documents.

Lets say I have the following files (on disk):

```
/foo/bar/schema/base.json
/foo/bar/schema/model/model.json
```

The base.json like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "/schema/base",
  "title": "Base Response",
  "description": "Schema descriptions of common properties of a response",
  "type": [ "object" ],

  "definitions": {
    "data": {
      "descrpition": "The response data is encapsulated within here",
      "example": "true",
      "type": [ "object", "array", "boolean", "null" ]
    }
  },

  "properties": {
    "data": { "$ref" : "#/definitions/data" }
  }
}
```

The model.json file is something like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "/schema/model/model",
  "type": "object",

  "$ref": "/schema/base.json"
}
```

The $ref value in the model.json is what I am asking about.  My understanding of the standard was that between the id and $ref of the document, we should be able to find the document.

Alternatively, I wondered whether something like:

```
"$ref": "../../base.json"
```

Would work?

But neither of those solutions seem to work using either Python or PHP libraries I've tried.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, different libraries tackle `$ref` resolution in different ways, so you will need to follow their specific documentation to figure out the exact details.  But below is some general information about `$ref` resolution that you might find helpful.

Think of your schema document as webpage you are viewing in a browser.  The `id` represents the URL in your browser's URL bar.  It must be a full absolute normalized URL, just like in your browser.

```
{
  "id": "file:///path/to/project/foo/bar/schema/model/model.json"
}
```

Think of `$ref` like a link in the webpage you are viewing in the browser.  In can be absolute or relative, just like in your browser.  A relative `$ref` will resolve following the same rules as a link on a webpage.  For example, I would expect all `$ref`s in the following JSON to resolve to the same value. *(Note: it is not valid to use more than one `$ref`.  This is just for illustration.)*

```
{
  "id": "file:///path/to/project/foo/bar/schema/model/model.json",
  "$ref": "file:///path/to/project/foo/bar/schema/base.json",
  "$ref": "/path/to/project/foo/bar/schema/base.json",
  "$ref": "../model.json"
}
```

If `id` is not present, the URI used to retrieve the schema should be assumed to be the `id`.  In this case `file:///path/to/project/foo/bar/schema/model/model.json`.

That's how it's supposed to work from a high level, but implementations  vary in how they implement this.  Some require the library to be setup in particular way.  For example, a PHP validator I've used requires you to register all your schemas into a `SchemaStore` before they can be referenced.

Reference: http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor27

Comment: Great explanation - thanks.  I think the main part I'd fallen down on was the meaning of the ID field, and also the intricacies of the given libraries.